# Is there any way to embed a Google Doc into sites via a panel in apps script?

Tags: embed, panel, google-apps-script, google-docs

Are there any plans in the works to embed Google Docs into a site via a Google apps script? If not, is there a workaround - this would be a very cool (not to mention invaluable) service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can embed a Google Doc into a site directly without an Apps Script.
2. If you want to embed the doc inside an apps script and then put the script into a Google Site, it is not possible using a panel. However, it **might** be possible using [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_html). You can try putting in the iframe code that you get from your doc in the html page. I'm not sure if it will go through the Caja sanitizer or not

Comment: Thanks...I've been playing around with HTML Service - I think it will work if I link directly to the Doc and publish it.

Comment: It works fine in HTML service, but it would be great to be able to display that blob in GAS.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that page:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/embedding_docslist_in_sites

It gives a lot of examples and guides to make apps with Google script

I've tried to do some exercises and it works fine!

```
function showFolderInSite() {
  var files = DocsList.getFolderById("FOLDER_ID").getFiles();
  var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("PAGE_URL");
   for(i in files){
     page.addWebAttachment(files[i].getName(), '', files[i].getUrl());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to embed a Google Document, not the DocsList.